# Place an image in div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, getelementbyid, appendchild

I am trying to build a Baccarat game, and want to place an image of each card in a `div` that is nested in a `li` - list item.  I have an empty image tag in a `div` with an `id` tag, and have created a Card Object in Javascript that has a "name", "suit" and "value".  The "name" and "suit" relate to the file name for each card (ie. AceSpades, TenDiamonds, JackClubs...etc.) located in the local "images" folder as a ".png".  When I run the code I am getting a "Cannot read property 'appendChild of null".

Below is an excerpt from the javascript code I have so far to give an idea of where I am coming from:

```
function card(name, suit, value) {
  this.name = name;
  this.suit = suit;
  this.value = value;
}

var cardsInDeck = [];
var suits = ["Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"];
var names = ["Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"];
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var card;

for (var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        cardsInDeck.push(new card(names[j], suits[i], values[j]));
    }
}

var b1, b2, b3, p1, p2, p3;

var drawOne = function() {
   var card = cardsInDeck.pop();
   return card;
}

var initialDealOut = function() {
  b1 = drawOne();
  p1 = drawOne();

  b2 = drawOne();
  p2 = drawOne();
}

initialDealOut();

var b1n = b1.name + b1.suit;
```

The code that I am trying to use to place the image in the `div` is:

```
var b1Image = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('b1');
  var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = "image/" + b1n + ".png";
  div.appendChild(image);
}

b1Image();
```

The core HTML for where I want to place the images is:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="cards">
    <li class="box">
      <div class="card" id="b1">
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have searched out a number of responses relating to similar questions, but of the answers that were given none seem to work the way I've tried implementing them.  I am new to programming, so I am sure this is an easy fix, but I am more than likely not approaching it correctly.

I apologize in advance for any confusion this questions brings with it and appreciate any assistance anyone can lend to help solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The code was updated.

You are trying the run the function `b1Image()` before the page has loaded. 
Using an event handler or adding `onload="b1Image()"` to the body tag would run the code after the page has loaded.
Also, don't run the function in your script file or script tag.

Before Edit:

Running `var b1n = b1.name + b1.suit;` without initializing `b1` could be the source of problems.

Run the function `initialDealOut` to initialize it before assigning it `b1n` if you haven't.

Comment: Also, where are you calling `b1Image()` function?

Comment: In my full version it has...this was just a portion of the script to help explain what I am trying to accomplish.  I just updated the code to reflect that, thank you.

Comment: So my main issue was that I had the link to the script tag in the head tag instead at the bottom of the bottom tag...which seems like a rookie mistake.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need an `id` for the `img` tag and Javascript (jQuery) can change the `src`

```
<img id='my_image' src="">
```

Then in jQuery

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","image.jpg");
```

Comment: So I've tried using your suggestion there, and it does eliminate the error message in the console, but I am still not getting an image to show up...I tried adding an ID tag to the IMG id="bank1":
    $('#bank1').attr("src", "images/" + b1n + ".png");